# Looking for something like git add -i, but for reset

Tags: git

I use git on a large project via the terminal. This works great most of the time, but I keep coming back to one use case which I can't seem to find a suitable solution for.

When adding files I can use `git add -i` and select files or chunks interactively. This is great and I use it often.

When I want to blow away a change I have made to a file I want to use something similar. I.e. `git reset -i`. But this doesn't exist. I know that I can use `git reset -- file.ext`, but this becomes very cumbersome when your file path is extremely long (think java packages).

My usual workflow is to fire up a GUI and do it in there. Are there any better ways to reset files?

Comment: Have you looked at http://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html

Comment: @XYZ927 any particular part? It is a pretty wide reaching post and I couldn't see anything that jumped out as a solution

Comment: It shows the scope of `reset` and hopefully will help in explaining the "whys" of my answer below, it's one of the first sources I read in helping me get to grips with `reset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git reset -p` to interactively choose chunks which should be reset from the index. It’s basically the inverse of `git add -p` and can be used to removed individual chunks from the index.

For example when you want to add all but a few lines of file `example.txt`, you can first add all changes using `git add example.txt` and then interactively find the chunks you want to remove from the index using `git reset -p example.txt`. You will end up with the same result like when you used `git add -p example.txt` in the first place and selected all chunks except those.

Comment: I think this is the nearest I will get to something like `git reset -i`, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you made changes to the file (whose change you want to blow away), but have not yet committed those changes, try using a `git reset --hard` to get your repo back.  If this doesn't work, try to run a `git reset HEAD~` and see if you can push your extremely long file.  Also, if you indeed did not yet commit the changes that you want to reset, simply try `git status` to explore what you need. But then again, if you have already pushed your changes, the process is a bit different and I encourage you to use `gitk --all --date-order` to explore around what git references outside of the current branch that you are in need of modification.  Also, if you have made changes that you have not yet set up, try using `git checkout -- .` to remove them (however, be careful with this one as there is probably no recovery of the files that you have made changes to and want to reset them with this option).